# Too many listeners for document?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, dom-events, event-listener

**Setup**

I've got a reusable custom dropdown menu, the rough framework is something like:

```
var List = (function() {

    // Custom list prototype stuffs...

    function ListObj(el, options) {     
        this._init(el);
    }

    ListObj.prototype._init = function(el) {
        var self = this;
        self.menu = el;
    }   

    // Expose an init function
    return {
        init : function(el, options) {
            new ListObj(el, options);
        }
    };

})();
```

And each menu is initialized with something like:

```
var ddlist = document.querySelector('.ddlist');
DDList.init(ddlist, options);
```

This all works as expected.

**What I want**

One behaviour I'd like each menu to have is to *automatically minimize* if a click occurs that isn't within the menu itself.

**What I've done**

Instead of having a single click listener for the document, and then having to add each menu and check where the click was, I've decided to add the document click listener within the `_init` method above:

```
ListObj.prototype._init = function(el) {
    var self = this;
    self.menu = el;

    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var el = e.target;

        if(self.menu === el || self.menu.contains(el)) {
            // Click was inside menu
            // Perform whatever tasks
        }else {
            // Click was outside of (this) menu, so minimize
            self.menu.minimize();
        }
    });

}
```

This way, each individual menu is automatically initialized with the behaviour to monitor document clicks, and either minimize if click is not within the menu, or perform whatever task is required.

This works perfectly. Of particular interest to me is that I can dynamically create new dropdown menus without having to add them to the document click listener, and I don't have to fight with `event.stopPropagation();` (I'd rather cut off my foot).

**But... Will my computer explode?**

This is all for a single-page webapp, which means that many dozens or hundreds of these menus could be created (and removed). My concern is that all these document click listeners will pile up and cause performance issues.

If I do something like...

```
document.getElementById('someMenu').remove();
```

will JS garbage collection know that it can do away with the one document click listener? Or will the listener persist until the end of days? If the latter, is there any way that I can remove that particular listener when the menu is removed?

An important caviate is that the menu will likely never directly be removed, but rather its parent will be removed - so `.remove()` will never act on the menu directly.

Much thanks!

**Just tested...**

I created two menus and then deleted one of them (`.remove()`). Even though the one menu was removed, the document click listener within still fires for every click. This seems to suggest that garbage collection will *not* handle this mess, and I will end up with countless listeners.

So, now what?

Comment: If you add an event listener to the document, that listener will keep existing, even if the object that created the listener (and contains the callback) has been removed. The cleanest solution is to remove a listener before removing the menu with `document.removeEventListener`. You can also bind the listener to the dom elements inside the menu. Then, when you remove the menu, the listener will also be removed. As a last option you could just have one listener on the document, and when someone clicks in the document, you iterate through all menus and tell them to close.

Comment: *Breaking Story*! Computer explodes due to badly programmed web page, stay tuned for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the function a name, so you can then remove the event listener.

```
ListObj.prototype._init = function(el) {
    var self = this;
    self.menu = el;
    self.click_handler = function(e) {
        var el = e.target;
        if (!document.contains(self.menu)) { // This element has been removed from DOM
            document.removeEventListener("click", self.click_handler);
            return;
        }
        if(self.menu === el || self.menu.contains(el)) {
            // Click was inside menu
            // Perform whatever tasks
        }else {
            // Click was outside of (this) menu, so minimize
            self.menu.minimize();
        }
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", self.click_handler);

}
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for, but couldn't figure out how to reference each specific instance of the listener.